# Find how many People Like dancing Only,People Like Movies

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

A survey was conducted among 402 persons regarding their interest in movies,dancing and games it was found that

(i) 100 People Like games. (ii) 142 People Like movies or dancing but not games. (iii) 220 People like neither games nor movies. (iv) 262 people do not like movies

I`m having a hard time making the equations for this

(if n is number of people who don`t like games,movies,dancing)

Comment: Velcome to our site!

Comment: Do you mean $100$ people like only games? In other case, if $142$ people like movies or dancing but not games and only $100$ people like games, then there are people not liking movies, dancing or gaming. Is it correct?

Comment: @mfl 100 people like games only

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen thanks

Comment: How is it possible that $262$ people do not like movies and $220$ people like neither games nor movies?

Comment: @mfl Same here If needed I can provide the answer at back of the book

Answer (score 0):

You have to make variables before you can make equations. e.g. you might make the variables

- $A$ = the number of people who like games and like movies and like dancing
- $B$ = the number of people who like games and like moves and do not like dancing
- $C$ = the number of people who like games and do not like movies and like dancing
- $D$ = the number of people who like games and do not like moves and do not like dancing
- $E$ = ...

More clever choices are surely possible, but if you can't see how to solve the problem efficiently with clever choices, then make the unclever choices that *will* let you encode the problem, albeit requiring a bit more work to solve.